# Updating dictionary with tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, eager-execution

I am facing a problem and I cannot seem to find the solution anywhere else, so I decided to post my question here (I have basic knowledge of tensorflow but quite new):

I wrote a simple code in python to illustrate what I want to do.

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    def generated_dict():
       graph = {'input': tf.Variable(2)}
       graph['layer_1'] = tf.square(graph['input'])
       graph['layer_2'] = tf.add(graph['input'], graph['layer_1'])
       return graph

    graph = generated_dict()
    print("boo = " + str(graph['layer_2']))

    graph['input'].assign(tf.constant(3))
    print("far = " + str(graph['layer_2']))
```

On this sample code, I would like tensorflow to update the whole dictionary when I assign a new input value by doing `graph['input'].assign(tf.constant(3))` . Basically, right now I obtain

```
boo = tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int32) # 2²+2
far = tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int32) # 2²+2
```

which is normal because of eager execution of my code. However I would like the dictionary to update its values with my new input and to get :

```
boo = tf.Tensor(6, shape=(), dtype=int32) #2²+2
far = tf.Tensor(12, shape=(), dtype=int32) #3²+3
```

I have the feeling I should be using tf.function() but I am not sure how I should proceed with it. I tried `graph = tf.function(generated_graph)()` but I did not help.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. I have the feeling that you are trying to use TensorFlow in a way it is not really designed for, and that it would make your life easier to do it some other way (using an estimator or keras).

Comment: I am trying to transform a code I found in a course from tensorflow 1.x to tensorflow 2.1. In the original code (tf 1.x) to do what I am trying to do, it was simply done by using `sess.run(graph['input'].assign(tf.constant(3)))`. I did not think it would be complicated in tensorflow 2.1.

Comment: It's probably not what you want to hear, but I suggest you don't : concepts in tensorflow 1 and 2 are quite different. I will try to come up with an answer that explains how I would do it in TF2. I suggest you stop following that course and follow instead the [tutorials on tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials). Trying to learn TF1 in TF2 will be quite a frustrating experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when trying to adapt TF1 code into TF2, I suggest to read the guide :
[Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#converting_models).

TF2 changed the base design of tensorflow from running ops in a graph to eager execution. It means that writing code in TF2 is quite close to writing code in normal python : all the abstraction, graph creation, etc, is done under the hood.

Your complicated design does not need to exists in TF2, just write a simple python function. You can even use normal operators instead of tensorflow functions. There will be converted into tensorflow operators. Optionally, you can use the [`tf.function` decorator for performances](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).

```
@tf.function
def my_graph(x):
     return x**2 + x
```

Now, if you want to feed data in that function, you just need to call it with a value :

```
>>> my_graph(tf.constant(3))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=12>
>>> my_graph(tf.constant(2))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>
```

Comment: I turned myself toward a different approach as you suggested. I figured I will have better luck with tf.keras than trying to transpose the code. Thanks for your reply to my answer.